# How to make react admin data provider to accept createMany?

Tags: react-admin

I want to implement an import csv button for my react admin application.

I would like my data provider to accept createMany and not fall back to a single create for each row in the csv.

Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making multiple calls for each row in a custom 'createMany', would it not be better to send ALL information to the API in one call and let the server handle the import for each row?

Of course, depending on what you are importing, you may need to setup background tasks on the server to prevent connection timeouts or letting the user wait for the entire import to finish.

Our system uses a .csv import system as well and is setup in the following manner:
-After selecting a .csv file, a simple preview is shown.
-After starting the import, the file is uploaded (together with additional info in one POST method), the task itself gets delegated to a background worker, and the user receives a message to check back shortly to see if the import has finished.

This way, even if the import takes an hour, the user is free to use the rest of the program instead of having to wait.